# Need help with classes modeling

Tags: design-patterns, class

I've being studying some OO concepts, like design patterns, clean code and some other stuff and i still have some doubts about how to proceed. For instance, lets take a look at my example.

I have a Person class that is a model. I want to add some validations to a person, like check if the age corresponds with the birth date and check if the name contains valid characters.

I have two approachs, but i dont know wich one i should use.

Approach one:
I create a new class called:

```
class ValidatePerson {}
```

and the the class have the methods: "validateAge()" and "validateName()" and every vallidation that i need i will have to implement a new method.

Approach two:
I create a abstract class called:
 ValidatePerson {} that will have some commum methods to all validation and the i would have:

```
class ValidatePersonAge extends ValidatePerson { validate();} 
class ValidatePersonName extends ValidatePerson {validate();}
```

I want to choose for approach two, cause every new validation rule that i will have to add will be a new class and wont affect the others. Like, if i need to alter something in the commum method that the new rule needs, i could just overwrite it. On the first approach, i would have to add another method and then create another method or alter the one thats already working for the others, that could make then crash.

The thing is that im kind of confused to all this, since im new to programming and i would like to see some help and explanation about it. I've also read that classes should be closed for changing but open for expanding (or something like  this).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. What _exactly_ are you looking for help with?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific correct answer. The design should always be in context of your problem domain and business context. So here are various options

**Option 1**
Person class has a vailidate() method that you can call to perform all he validations on its current state.

Pros

- better encapsulation
- changes are localized to 1 single class
- validation is performed after setting all the properties

Cons

- Person might be in invalid state before the validate() method is called hence no fail fast
- Can't have different validation rules for different context

**Option 2**
Each property has its own validateXXX() method in the Person class. Each setXXX() method is going to call corresponding validateXXX() method.

Pros

- better encapsulation
- changes are localized to 1 single class
- Fail fast behavior i.e. Person object will never be an invalid state

Cons

- might be overkill based on the context
- Can't have different validation rules for different context

**Option 3**
You could have a PersonBuilder that contains these validation checks. The builder will perfrom these validations before it builds the Person object. This way once the Person object is built, it satisfies all the validations and invariants.

Pros

- You have externalized the validations to a builder class hence you can have different validation rules for different contexts
- Construnction logic is separated from the domain object
- Person class can be made immutable once constructed

Cons

- Might be a overkill in some scenarios

---

Your option 2 is not correct because ValidatePersonAge IS NOT same as ValidatePerson. You are not validating the person entirely but only validating his age. So they are semantically different.